# Windows 7 gadgets changing place when I move from dual monitor to a single one

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, desktop-gadget

I am using Windows 7 on my laptop.
At the office, I have a dual monitor setup through my docking station while at home or during meetings I use my laptop with its single monitor.
Whenever I move between these two setups, Windows 7 plays with the location of the gadgets I have and I need to rearrange them each time.
Is there a way to tell it to store these settings and locations (both gadgets and icons) so that it will remember their placement on the dual monitor setup and it will remember a different placement for the single monitor setup?

Comment: comment from [Steve M.](http://superuser.com/users/38709/steve-m): I have exactly the same problem!! This drives me crazy as I move between the laptop and docking station several times each day.  Anyone know of a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer but a work around which works for me is a gadget called [7 sidebar](http://nes.bplaced.net/sidebar7.html). This gadget has an option to hard set it to a given monitor and then you can place all gadgets inside it (much like the sidebar in Vista). 
This means my gadgets are always placed back on the correct monitor. The drawback is of course all gadgets has to be inside the "sidebar" and cannot be placed freely on the desktop...

Answer (score 0):

You can manually restore gadgets' settings in file located here:

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows Sidebar\Settings.ini
```

with something like

```
copy /y BackupDual.ini Settings.ini
```

every time you switch your screen setup, or get it triggered by some specialized application. Such an app could also offer desktop icons restoring.